# Registry Error: JAVA 1.7 instead of 1.6

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, java-6

I got this error while installing Android Development bundle.

I have installed both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 in my Windows 8 PC. I downloaded the ADT bundle and opened the eclipse.exe bundle and got this error.

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'

has value '1.5', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I went to the registry error and followed the following procedure and it worked.

- In the START menu type "regedit" to open the Registry (be careful doing this)
- Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" on the left-hand side registry explorer/tree menu
- Click "SOFTWARE" within the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" registries
- Click "JavaSoft" within the "SOFTWARE" registries
- Click "Java Runtime Environment" within the "JavaSoft" list of registries
- Highlight "CurrentVersion" (should see it in the main registry key explorer window on the right)
- Change version to "1.7"

My doubt is what version of Java is Eclipse using. If I want to use the Java version 6.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit the **eclipse.ini** file. Before `-vmargs` (maybe best on top of the file) you could insert `-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6...\bin\javaw.exe` (the path to your preferred JRE or JDK).

Then Eclipse uses that.

Answer (score 0):

About your question on version of JAVA to use,

You need to use JDK 1.6. Check the System requirements in the link below.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Do not forget to add Java(bin of jdk and jre) to the Windows path

Answer (score -1):

You might have 2 version of jdk installed in your system.

Comment: As the OP claims that he has _installed both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7_, this is quite obvious and no solution to the OP's problem.